# Why my Cloud Print Not Working?

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

I just print the pdf file from my sd card. But nothing happen when i click my print button.

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Print" />
```

**main.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//to declare a button
Button btnPrint;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnPrint = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //set OnclickListener
    btnPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //check the network is available or not
            if(isNetworkAvailable() == false){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Connection Not Available Please Try Again Later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "personal/Brain Stuff.pdf");
                Intent printIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PrintDialogActivity.class);
                printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
                printIntent.putExtra("Title","Test Print");
            }
        }
    });
}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    //if no network is available means network ingo will be null
    //otherwise check if we are connected
    if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        Log.e("Network Testing","Available");
        return true;
    }
    Log.e("Network Testing","No Network Available");
    return false;
}
```

}

**print_dialog.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

When i click my button nothing happen just same screen is there. and i also add **PrintDialogActivity**. what i  make a mistake ? Guide me

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the activity with

```
startActivity(printIntent);
```

Comment: you are right now redirect to login page and i login but select printer click print mean no print out process is start. and Import one is my printer names are something like blur

Comment: i reconnect my printer now okay but still print not working